# Observable from Subject

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm trying to create actions from updates from a RX Subject

It's working but I get the error below.

Here is my Epic

```
export function uploadSceneFile(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(CREATE_SCENE_SUCCESS)
    .mergeMap(({payload}) =>
      UploadSceneWithFile(payload)
        .subscribe(res => {
          if (res.progress > 0)
            store.dispatch(uploadSceneProgress(res))
          else if(res.progress === -1){
            store.dispatch(uploadSceneSuccess(res))
            requestSceneProcessing(res).map(res => {
            })
          }

        })
    )
}
```

And here is the Subject

```
export function UploadSceneWithFile(scene){

  const subject$ = new Subject()

  const uploader = new S3Upload({
    getSignedUrl: getSignedUrl,
    uploadRequestHeaders: {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'},
    contentType: scene.file.type,
    contentDisposition: 'auto',
    s3path: 'assets/',
    onError:()=>subject$.next('error'),
    onProgress: (val)=> subject$.next({...scene,progress:val}),
    onFinishS3Put: ()=>subject$.next({...scene,progress:-1}),
  })
  uploader.uploadFile(scene.file)

  return subject$
}
```

I read from a previous post that I'm supposed to be using .map, not .subscribe but nothing happens if I don't subscribe (the upload doesn't happen)

What's the best way of doing this?

```
subscribeToResult.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:132)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:129)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:112)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at FilterSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:89)
    at FilterSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Subject../node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
    at createEpicMiddleware.js:60
    at createEpicMiddleware.js:59
    at SafeSubscriber.dispatch [as _next] (applyMiddleware.js:35)
    at
```

Comment: Are you using ngrx effects?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you subscribe inside `mergeMap` and return a `Subscription` which is invalid. The callback needs to return only Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I'm not sure what exactly you need to do but if you need to perform some side-effects you can use `do()` operator instead of subscribing.

```
export function uploadSceneFile(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(CREATE_SCENE_SUCCESS)
    .mergeMap(({ payload }) => UploadSceneWithFile(payload)
      .do(res => {
        ...
      })
    )
}
```

Or it looks like you could put do after `mergeMap` as well:

```
export function uploadSceneFile(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(CREATE_SCENE_SUCCESS)
    .mergeMap(({ payload }) => UploadSceneWithFile(payload))
    .do(res => {
      ...
    });
}
```